# Can you pass values through the url in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Juan

Hello I was hoping a Shopify expert could advise me.

I already have a collections template in use and  I need to prepare this layout to work within Shopify as something supplementary to the whole ecommerce function.

http://www.psd2htmlservice.com/streetstyles.jpg

As you can see you would click on the thumbnails and a larger corresponding image appears on the left along with some text at the top.

As I say there's no ecommerce element attached to this part of the site but I was thinking each image could be a product added to a collection.  I'm well versed on looping through product images and collections but I'm not sure how to achieve the functionality required keeping in mind (as I understand it)  you can't pass a value through the url in liquid.  All I can think of would be to use a new page that uses a template with some liquid code hardcoded in each time....but surely there would be a more streamlined way.

I would appreciate any help.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you go into more detail about the particular problem you're running up against?

Comment: Yeah sure.....I've already got a collections page all set up....http://corwin-group7120.myshopify.com/collections/women  so this particular page in the screenshot is something extra.....following a different layout as well......I basically want  to be able  to loop through a different collection each time the relevant one is clicked through to on this "bespoke" page...I thought it could do it with a query string but it seems you can't in Shopify....any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Each collection in your shop has it's own page (e.g. collections/men, collections/women, collections/streetstyles) so you can link directly to those urls from another page to display the correct products. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 8):

No, unfortunately you can not (as of June 2014)

There is a [feature request](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/url-parameters-in-liquid-171887) called `Expose current URL in Liquid` for this but it has not yet been implemented.

Also, there are several older pages where this is asked on the Shopify help forms, probably the most direct is [Pass variables to liquid template via URL](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/pass-variables-to-liquid-template-via-url-32784) which mentions:

> You can't do this:
>
> `{{ request.myvar }}`
>
> to read `myVal`.

The common suggestions on the forums include:

1. Using Javascript to read the URL and use it to modify the page or interact with the user,
2. Create an [application proxy](http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies) which would be a page on your own server that it served up via a special link on your Shopify site (but it still does not actually allow you to access query variables in Liquid)

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can find it in liquid via `{{content_for_header}}` actually. Whether or not Shopify will remove from `content_for_header` in the future I can't answer, but you CAN get this in liquid.

```
{%- capture contentForQuerystring -%}{{ content_for_header }}{%- endcapture -%}

{%- assign pageUrl = contentForQuerystring | split:'"pageurl":"' | last | split:'"' | first | split:'.myshopify.com' | last |
   replace:'\/','/' | 
   replace:'%20',' ' | 
   replace:'\u0026','&'
-%}
```

Check out this sample for how I've used this in the past:
https://www.channelape.com/shopify/build-custom-json-api-shopify-liquid/

Comment: Credit to Jason at FreakDesign for having a clean example here also: https://github.com/freakdesign/Shopify-code-snippets/tree/master/Get%20querystring%20in%20Shopify%20Liquid

Comment: It's mind blowing how much help Jason's code snippets and projects have been when I've run into questions.